# MongoDB find() - trying to construct a complex date query

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query

I'm trying to write a rather fiddly MongoDB query that returns a set of results (events) filtered only for future events.

Unfortunately the data schema of these events is a little frustrating. The user can set up an event with a specific end date (this is fine to work with), or they can select a recurrence that ends on a specific date (also fine)..

however they can also select the option for the event to recur every X days/weeks/months (there is a type field to select which of these) for a total of Y recurrences. So if I want to calculate an effective ending date I need to use all three of these variables in my query.

I'm struggling with the syntax for manipulating dates in a MongoDB query, using data from within the database to construct a new date object...

Here is the condition I have constructed so far, am trying to complete the 3 rows that have /* */ comments.

If anybody knows a way to do this, I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
$or: [
    { 'when.endingDate': { $gte: new Date() } },
    { 'when.recurring.forever': { $eq: true } },
    { 'when.multipleDays': { $eq: true } },
    {
      $and: [
        { 'when.recurring.occurences': { $gte: 1 } },
        { $or: [
          { $and: [
            { 'when.recurring.type': { $eq: 'day' } },
            { /* when.endingDate + when.recurring.occurences * when.recurring.every * days >= new Date() */ }
          ] },
          {
            $and: [
              { 'when.recurring.type': { $eq: 'week' } },
              { /* when.endingDate + when.recurring.occurences * when.recurring.every * week >= new Date() */ }
            ]
          },
          {
            $and: [
              { 'when.recurring.type': { $eq: 'month' } },
              { /* when.endingDate + when.recurring.occurences X when.recurring.every * month >= new Date() */ }
            ]
          }
        ] }
      ]
    },
    { $and: [
      { 'when.repeat': { $eq: true } },
      { 'when.recurring.until': { $gte: new Date() } }
    ] }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cram a whole lot of business logic into your mongodb query.

I would choose one of the below approaches:

- stream the DB to application and run the above logic in an actual programming language (preferred);
- prepare the data for the above query. make helper fields and update them regularly via a scheduled job.